# Change Local Path for CakePHP over II6 and windows 2003

Tags: cakephp, iis-6, cakephp-2.0, isapi-rewrite, cakephp-2.2

I have followed this article to configure CakePHP over II6:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jamesmking/2008/04/12/cakephp-on-iis6-with-fastcgi-sql-server-2005-and-isapi_rewrite

But i want to change the "Local Path" from "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CakePHP\app\webroot" to "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\" in order to be able to execute different web applications and not only the CakePHP one.

I have tried it changing the "local path" on the IIS manager but i doesn't work. I guess it should be something related with the ISAPI Rewrite and its conditions.

Do you know how could I make the needed changes in order to make it work?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Move the .htaccess file in the root of the site's root folder.

Comment: .htaccess doesnt run with II6 as far as i know. (and with IIS 7 either) ISS 6 has to use ISAPI_Rewrite3 and in IIS 7 you can make it work with web.config files instead.